# Saving efficiently some large variables using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question on how to save large variables created in MATLAB. I have some `cell` variables (`A`, `B`, `C`) . Each of those occupies more than 2Gb of memory.
At the moment I'm saving them by typing

```
savefile = 'All.mat';
save(savefile, 'A', 'B', 'C', '-v7.3')
```

It takes a while. I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to store them, for example by converting them to some other file extension. Any suggestion?

Comment: Saving that many data will take a long time, not much you can do about it. Whether you can use another file extension depends mainly on two things: your use case and your data type. If those cells contain all kinds of different data types, and you need these later in MATLAB, there's not much choice. If OTOH you have only numeric double values (and could thus use a matrix) you can use different formats (csv, binary etc), which might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

If disk space is not an issue for you, then you can try turning off compression:

```
save(savefile, 'A', 'B', 'C', '-v7.3', '-nocompression')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to save A, B and C in 3 different files? It is what I am generally doing.

Or if you want to have them in the same file you could also save a subset of each cell (e.g. 10) in different files?